# Merge 3 lists into 1 list

Tags: python, list, merge

I want to merge 3 lists in to a single list.
For example, I have three lists:

```
a = [0, 3, 6, 9]
b = [1, 4, 7, 10]
c = [2, 5, 8, 11]
```

and finally I want to get

```
merged = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

out of `a`, `b`, `c`

Are there any faster way to merge these 3 lists?
Here's my code:

```
merged = []
a = [0, 3, 6, 9]
b = [1, 4, 7, 10]
c = [2, 5, 8, 11]
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    merged.append(a[i])
    merged.append(b[i])
    merged.append(c[i])
```

Comment: Put the lists into a list (or tuple, etc.) of lists, and then flatten that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import itertools as it

list(it.chain.from_iterable(it.izip(a,b,c)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [0, 3, 6, 9]
b = [1, 4, 7, 10]
c = [2, 5, 8, 11]
d=[]
print [j  for i in zip(a,b,c) for j in i]
```

Output:`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce is another option:

```
>>> a = [0, 3, 6, 9]
b = [1, 4, 7, 10]
c = [2, 5, 8, 11]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: list(x)+list(y), zip(a,b, c))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: @Baruchel, zip is returning a list of tuples, so you need to wrap the values into a list before doing the add.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
a = [0, 3, 6, 9]
b = [1, 4, 7, 10]
c = [2, 5, 8, 11]
merged=a+b+c
merged.sort()
```

Since you are adding the list the merged list will contains all values from abc but not in the correct order.That's why I used .sort() to sort the list