# How to add two lists together, avoid repetitions, and order elements?

Tags: python

I have two lists filled with integers. I wish to add them together such that:

1. the output list has no duplicate elements,
2. is in order, and
3. contains the union of both lists.

Is there any way to do so without creating my own custom function? If not, what would a neat and tidy procedure look like?

For instance:

```
list1 = [1, 10, 2]
list2 = [3, 4, 10]
```

Output:

```
outputlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: So I have done it what I consider to be the lengthy way to go about it. Which is for each element in the first list, check if it is in the second if so, remove it. Then add the lists, and then simply sort them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python merge 3 lists into 1 list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761978/python-merge-3-lists-into-1-list)

Comment: who stole the  **3** ?

Comment: i believe when being edited it was lost, it is now fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
combined = [list1, list2]
union = list(set().union(*combined))
```

This takes advantage of the predefined `method` (`.union()`) of `set()` , which is what you need here.

`combined` can have as many elements inside it, as the asterisk in `*combined` means that the union of *all* of the elements is found.

Also, I `list()`ed the result but you could leave it as a `set()`.

As @glibdud states in the comments, it's possible that this might produce a sorted list, but it's not guaranteed, so use `sorted()` to ensure that it's ordered. (like this `union = sorted(list(set().union(*combined)))`)

Comment: Note that the fact that this produces a sorted result is somewhat accidental. You'll want to do `sorted(set()...)` instead of `list(set()...)` to be sure. (Try adding some larger numbers into the lists.)

Comment: if I can nitpick your wording: "It's possible that this might not produce a sorted list" is like saying "it's possible that shuffling a deck of cards won't produce a sorted deck." It's inverse. It's *possible* that `list(some_set)` will produce a sorted list, but there's no reason it should. (also no need to call `list` before `sorted` -- `sorted` returns a list.)

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = [1, 10, 2]
l2 = [3, 4, 10]

sorted(list(set(l1 + l2)))
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 10]
```

Comment: Please enlighten me as to the difference between a union without duplicates and a list of unique elements.

Comment: Note that the fact that this produces a sorted result is somewhat accidental. You'll want to do `sorted(set()...)` instead of `list(set()...)` to be sure. (Try adding some larger numbers into the lists.)

Comment: I wonder if `set(l1+l2)` could be faster than `set().union(l1, l2)`, since the former must first concat the lists, while the latter has essentially no overhead

Comment: @glibdud I couldn't get it to generate a non-sorted list, although I also couldn't find any documentation regarding this behavior. Do you have a link?

Comment: @AdamSmith I think `set().union` is definitely consistently faster, but not substantially faster. This version is quite readable though.

Comment: Just adding a couple of 6-7 digit numbers did it for me. I don't have a link, but in general sets are considered unordered. They'll usually maintain order "accidentally" for small integers, but that's an implementation detail and shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: @AdamSmith This was the first solution that came to mind ... but I was sure that `itertools` would be quicker as it's designed for efficiency.